# How trunc datetime column with pandas?

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a column with dates in that format :

```
0      2013-12-12 10:51:51
1      2013-12-12 11:11:01
2      2013-12-12 11:19:22
3      2013-12-12 11:36:48
4      2013-12-12 11:36:48
```

and I want to trunc it to

```
0      10:51:51
1      11:11:01
2      11:19:22
3      11:36:48
4      11:36:48
```

I tried `df[":11]` but it trunc the column, not inside the column

Comment: Is this a string or a datetime colunmn? If string then `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x[11:])` else `df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.time())` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following:

```
In [145]:
# do this if the dtype is a string
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x[11:])
df
Out[145]:
   index      time
0      0  10:51:51
1      1  11:11:01
2      2  11:19:22
3      3  11:36:48
4      4  11:36:48
In [148]:
# do this if it's a datetime
df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.time())
df
Out[148]:
   index      time
0      0  10:51:51
1      1  11:11:01
2      2  11:19:22
3      3  11:36:48
4      4  11:36:48
```

Comment: It works great! I had just to make a copy of the dataframe then return it to avoid an error.

Comment: Well I need help again, I had to set the time column as the **index** and it doesn't work anymore. I tried `d.index = d.apply(lambda x: x.time())` but I got this error `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'time"`

Comment: You can just do `d.index = d.index.apply(lambda x: x.time())`, or just do this before you set it as an index

Comment: `d.index = d.index.apply(lambda x: x.time())` won't work. I finally managed to do it by doing a reset of the index, apply, and set again:

    `df.reset_index("time", inplace=True)
    df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: x.time())
    df.set_index("time", inplace=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`slice`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.slice.html#pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.slice), and if the column is not `str` you need to map to `str` as well:

```
>>> df.tic
0   2013-12-12 10:51:51
1   2013-12-12 11:11:01
2   2013-12-12 11:19:22
3   2013-12-12 11:36:48
4   2013-12-12 11:36:48
Name: tic, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> df.tic.map(str).str.slice(11)
0    10:51:51
1    11:11:01
2    11:19:22
3    11:36:48
4    11:36:48
Name: tic, dtype: object
```

If the column is `Timestamp` you may also, map to  `pd.Timestamp.time`:

```
>>> df.tic.map(pd.Timestamp.time)
0    10:51:51
1    11:11:01
2    11:19:22
3    11:36:48
4    11:36:48
Name: tic, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Though there are several ways to do this via string formatting and conversions, the best performance can be achieved by keeping the data in a numpy array. Compare the following:

Generate some data:

```
datetimes = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-02-01', freq='s'))
```

Convert to array of `datetime` objects:

```
%%timeit
datetimes.dt.time

7.41 s ± 747 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Keeping in numpy array

```
%%timeit

datetimes-datetimes.dt.floor(freq='D')

166 ms ± 50.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

For completeness sake that data compared:

```
df = pd.concat([
    datetimes.rename('input'), 
    (datetimes-datetimes.dt.floor(freq='D')).rename('using floor'), 
    datetimes.dt.time.rename('using time')
], axis=1).head()
```

Resulting data:

```
df.head(5)

    input               using floor     using time
0   2018-01-01 00:00:00     00:00:00    00:00:00
1   2018-01-01 00:00:01     00:00:01    00:00:01
2   2018-01-01 00:00:02     00:00:02    00:00:02
3   2018-01-01 00:00:03     00:00:03    00:00:03
4   2018-01-01 00:00:04     00:00:04    00:00:04
```

Resulting types:

```
df.dtypes

input           datetime64[ns]
using floor    timedelta64[ns]
using time              object
dtype: object
```